# JAXB inheritance via a Gradle plugin

Tags: jaxb, gradle-plugin

I'm converting a Java component from Maven to Gradle. Some of the classes are generated using org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin. In another component I had success using the Gradle plugin com.intershop.gradle.jaxb.
But the XSDs in this component include inheritance and I can't get the plugin to work.

The maven plugin requires an -Xinheritance switch. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent in the intershop plugin.
https://github.com/IntershopCommunicationsAG/jaxb-gradle-plugin

```
> Task :jaxbJavaGenName
[ant:xjc] [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance". Perhaps you meant "http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"?
[ant:xjc]   line 9 of file:/opt/tep-gradle/component/core/tres/src/main/resources/xsd/ManagementConsoleChangePasswordRequest.xsd
[ant:xjc]
[ant:xjc] [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance". Perhaps you meant "http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"?
[ant:xjc]   line 9 of file:/opt/tep-gradle/component/core/tres/src/main/resources/xsd/ManagementConsoleSignOnRequest.xsd
[ant:xjc]
[ant:xjc] [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance". Perhaps you meant "http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"?
[ant:xjc]   line 9 of file:/opt/tep-gradle/component/core/tres/src/main/resources/xsd/ManagementConsoleVerifyMFARequest.xsd
[ant:xjc]
```